# tkinter: label not displayed when pack() is called outside of a class' init function

Tags: python, tkinter

python version: 2.7

I'm trying to create a function that simply loads 2 images using tkinter. My code is:

```
from Tkinter import *

class ImageTest(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry('300x300')

        testImg = PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
        label1 = Label(self.gameWindow, image=testImg )
        label1.pack()
        label2 = Label(self.gameWindow, image=testImg )
        label2.pack()

        #self.init_test_screen()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def init_test_screen(self):

        testImg = PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
        label1 = Label(self.gameWindow, image=testImg )
        label1.pack()
        label2 = Label(self.gameWindow, image=testImg )
        label2.pack()

imagetest = ImageTest()
```

this works as expected but what I want to do is delegate the initialization of label1 and label2 to init_test_screen(). if I change my **init** to:

```
def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry('300x300')

        #testImg = PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
        #label1 = Label(self.gameWindow, image=testImg )
        #label1.pack()
        #label2 = Label(self.gameWindow, image=testImg )
        #label2.pack()

        self.init_test_screen()

        self.window.mainloop()
```

the 2 images are no longer displayed. any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to "testImg" is lost after the execution of "init_test_screen".
Just store it within the object using "self":

```
from Tkinter import *

class ImageTest(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry('300x300')

        self.init_test_screen()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def init_test_screen(self):

        self.testImg = PhotoImage(file='test.gif')
        label1 = Label(self.window, image=self.testImg )
        label1.pack()
        label2 = Label(self.window, image=self.testImg )
        label2.pack()

imagetest = ImageTest()
```

Comment: a better solution might be to pass self.window to init_test_screen. With that, `init_test_screen` doesn't have to know what its parent is, it is told what its parent is, making for looser coupling. Since it's all part of the same class that's not particularly important, unless `init_test_screen` might be used for more than one window.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm very new to Python and am very interested in implementing things the object-oriented way, would you be able to show the code that will contribute to looser coupling?

Comment: @BryanOakley I did as you suggested and changed init_test_screen to accept one parameterm parentWindow. from __init__ I passed self.window to init_test_screen. in init_test_screen I changed all self.window to parentWindow. thanks for the tip!